# Difference between stating helper methods in helper and controller files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, helper

In Ruby on Rails we can state a helper method in controllers e.g.

```
# app/controllers/my_controller.rb

class MyController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :helper_method_name

  ...

  private

  def helper_method_name
    ...
  end
end
```

and in helpers e.g.

```
# app/helpers/my_helper.rb

class MyHelper
  def helper_method_name
    ...
  end
end
```

What's the difference (in relation to access, usage, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

The method **helper_method** is to explicitly share some methods defined in the controller to make them available for the view.

This is used for any method that you need to access from both **controllers** and **helpers/views** (standard helper methods are not available in controllers).

Answer (score 0):

As ray said. You only want to use the **helper_method** when you really need to use it in **both** the controllers and helpers/views.

Generally, you want to use controller concerns and the helpers(views) for the respective methods as that's the convention.